# How to use AXUIElementCreateSystemWide() in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, accessibility

I try to run following code from a tutorial:

```
  AXUIElement element = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
```

I get following errors:

- Cannot find 'element' in scope
- Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
- Expected member name or constructor call after type name

I tried to fix it by adding

```
import Accessibility
import ApplicationServices
```

Both without success. Something must have changed recently?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is Objective-C.

In Swift:

```swift
let element: AXUIElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
```

or you can leave out type annotation:

```swift
let element = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
```

For the framework

```swift
import Cocoa
```

is enough.